# How to create k number of processes using fork() call, where k is not power of 2

Tags: c

Like n fork calls will create 2^n processes, but to specifically create
k processes what to do?

Comment: Call `fork` in a loop ***in the parent process only***?

Comment: Maybe think more than five seconds about your homework before asking?

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have to use thread concept instead of using fork().

```
for(i=0; i < Num_OF_Thread; i++)
      {
         pthread_create( &thread_id[i], NULL, print_message_function, NULL );
      }
void print_message_function(  )
    {
     // Task wich u want ro perform
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but i was asked to use fork only.